# Node.js - throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");

Tags: node.js

What does this mean?

```
throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
```

When I install a package and I incude I get that error!  Why?

I am usig express.

e.g.

npm install -g moment

m = require('moment');

Comment: What version of node and npm are you running? I just installed moment without any problems, so make sure you have the latest npm and node binaries.

Comment: I have the same problem. Clean install of Noce 0.6.18 via IISNode 0.1.19. This is running a basic script requiring the filesystem

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use it in a script, you have to install it locally. If you want to use it in a shell, install it globally.

http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/

Basically, run `npm install moment` without the `-g` flag and it will work.